# Twilio Prevent From Dialing Specific Numbers In Twilio Console

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Is there anyway to create a block list in twilio dashboard from dialing or making outbound call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Developer is control of [calling the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource), you can place a check before you execute an API call to see if the party is allowed to call a specific number.

Twilio Console does provide Voice [Geographic Permissions](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180168-What-Are-Geographic-Permissions-and-Why-do-They-Exist-) that allowed you to restrict calling to specific countries.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, the purpose we do it in twilio console because our twilio account is being used in multiple app.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a way to restrict the capabilities of the API keys to specific access. You would need to have others work through your own backend services which would in turn work with Twilio based on your logic and what you allow them to do.